# In App Billing sample application not working

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am new to android .. I have downloaded the In App billing sample application.. The package name of the sample application is com.example.dungeons .. But inorder to publish this application to android market I have to change the package name to something else because by default android doesn't allow the application with package name com.example to be published.. But when I change the package name  my application is getting crashed and my log cat doesn't show anything..

Any help on this ??

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: frome where you have change package name manifest or package explorer?

Comment: so just goto manifest file and change package name also.

Answer (score 1):

I think shlublu is right , in adding more to it.

1)first rename the package name com.example.dungeons

2)Open menifest file and change its activities package name in activity tag

< activity android:name="com.anotherexample.dungeons.SampleActivity" />

3)on all package please do ctrl+shift+o  so all files get its proper package 
4) if require clean the project and run

hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this comes from a discrepancy between your Android-manifest file and your Java source files:

if you have changed the package name in the manifest file without renaming the packages accordingly in your source files, your `Activities` won't start properly: the manifest file declares they belong to the new package name you have chosen but in your source files they are still belonging to `com.example.dungeons`.

About logcat, this is another question. You must have started your app in run mode instead of debug mode.